# tkinter listbox error - AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'tk'

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

I am new to tkinter and trying to make a listbox.
This is the code I am using, I keep getting the error AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'tk'.
What am I doing wrong?

```
from tkinter import *

def ListWindow():
    Listwindow = Tk()           
    Listwindow.title("Welcome")
    Listwindow.geometry("400x130")

    lbl_welcome = Label(Listwindow,text="Welcome to A list box!")
    lbl_welcome.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=10)

    myList = Listbox(Listwindow)
    myList.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=10)

    WidgetNames = ['Button', 'Canvas']
    for widget in WidgetNames:
        Listbox.insert(0, widget)
    myList.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=10)

def main():
    ListWindow()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: U have typos
its not Listbox.insert it should be myList.insert...
and 
above def main()  put line 
Listwindow.mainloop()

Comment: of course - silly me many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call method from `instance` of a widget. Right now you are trying to use Type as instance.

```
for widget in WidgetNames:
    myList.insert(0, widget)
```

Also, not sure which IDE you are using but even if some IDEs calls mainloop implicitly, it would be better to add it explicitly.

```
def ListWindow():
    Listwindow = Tk() 
    ....
    ....
    myList.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=10)
    Listwindow.mainloop()
```