# After() Command Refuses to Work (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, while-loop

I am attempting to create a loop in Tkinter, so naturally I turned to .After. This is my first time using Tkinter, and my first time using .After. Despite checking at least a dozen websites, I cannot get it to work. Here is a simplified recreation of my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import *
root = tk.Tk
a = 5
def Func():

    while not a == 5:
        print ('A does not equal five.')
        a += 1
root.after(0, Func)
root.mainloop()
```

However, it simply does not work. The mainloop does not fire, and no errors show up.

If this matters at all, I code on a Chromebook, on IDLE. Thanks in advance.

NOTE: My original code does open up frames, widgets, a canvas, and the like, this is just a quick and simplified version.

Comment: What is the purpose of using `after()` in your case?  As `after(0, ...)` is meaningless, you can simply call the `Func()` directly.

Comment: ***mainloop does not fire***: Didn't you get a root Window? This: `while not a == 5:` evals to `True`, therefore no ` print(...`

Answer (score 0):

When I tried running your code, I ran into some problems...

## `tk.Tk` is a type, to create and instance use `tk.Tk()`

First error: 
`AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'tk'`, 
I found a possible answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45234933/6934388
and changed `root = tk.Tk` to   `root = tk.Tk()` to create a Tk instance. If this is not what you intended to do, sorry!

## `Func()` tried to access a global

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment`. `a` was defined before  `Func()` and couldn't be accessed from within the function. To fix this, add `global a` inside the function (But from the perspective of a beginner I think you might want to be careful with using globals. Maybe change it to a parameter)

## `not a == 5` never fired

The code now ran but nothing is printed. To test whether the function worked I changed `a = 5` to `a = 0` to make it print something 5 times. After printing 5 times, the while-loop never triggers again, because the condition `not a == 5` is not met anymore and `a` can only (as of this code) be changed from within that loop.

Here is your code again, with the changes.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import *

root = tk.Tk() # Tk() to create an instance!
a = 0

def Func():
    global a # a is global

    while not a == 5:
        print ('A does not equal five.')
        a += 1

root.after(0, Func)
root.mainloop()
```

Hope this was what you were looking for!

Comment: Oh ok... I created it in about a minute probably should have put more effort into it, sorry. However, my actual problem has code that works, the .after function is the problem there.

Comment: Doesn't a Tkinter window show up when you run the code either?

Comment: Once again, this is my actual code... I'm too self-conscious to show it, sorry if that makes things difficult. But basically I just need a good explanation of the after statement, a dozen sites I checked did not help.

Comment: As far as I understand the `after` method, all it does is plan ahead for the execution of a method. You can then re-plan it in the method  itself if you want it to loop. You have a main 'root' object `Tk()` that can schedule the execution of a function using the `after` method. The way you used it was correct except by using a  while-loop inside your function, it probably halts the program until the loop stops.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first look at how `after` is defined:

> **after(ms, func=None, *args)** 
>       method of tkinter.Tk instance
>       Call function once after given time.

In order to achieve a loop effect, you have to schedule a `after` event inside your defined function so the function will call itself recursively until the condition is met. It should look something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

a = 0

def func(n):
    if n!=5:
        print (f'A is {n} and does not equal five.')
        n += 1
        root.after(1000, func, n)

func(a)

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

```
A is 0 and does not equal five.
A is 1 and does not equal five.
A is 2 and does not equal five.
A is 3 and does not equal five.
A is 4 and does not equal five.
```

Answer (score -1):

> The mainloop does not fire, and no errors show up.

- Declare variable `a = 0`. Using zero instead of 5 will cause fire.
- Add a parameter in `Func(a):` This will prevent `global`.
- Use **f-string format** to print in debug.
- Move `root.after` outside if `while/else` block. set delay to 100
  instead of zero.
- Add third parameter .`after(..,...a)`.
- Add callback `func(a)` before `root.mainloop()`

Snippet some modified same as your script:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import *
root = tk.Tk()
a = 0
def Func(a):

    while not a == 5:
        print (f'A is {a} and doen not equal five.')
        a += 1
    root.after(1000, Func, a)
Func(a)
root.mainloop()
```

Output:

```
A is 0 and doen not equal five.
A is 1 and doen not equal five.
A is 2 and doen not equal five.
A is 3 and doen not equal five.
A is 4 and doen not equal five.
```